# Marketing Cloud Custom Dashboard for inserted rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, dashboard, customization

Some users in Marketing Cloud need to check if some contacts are arriving in a Data Extension (the Data Extension is being filled up through an API). They wish to check hourly in a Dashboard how many Contacts arrived in the Data Extension, if none contact arrive in an hour, there is probably a problem with the API, so that will alert they to check with the internal IT team.

Is possible to create a Custom Dashboard to show how many Contacts arrived (rows inserted) in the Data Extension and let this Dashboard in Marekting Cloud homepage? (Somheting like the dashboard in Setup Page)

[image]

Or is possible to create it in a Cloud Pages (get the Data with SSJS), but let accessible only to Marketing Cloud users?

Comment: You can create it inside a Cloudpage, but would need to create your own authentication to limit access. See this article (https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-create-a-password-protected-marketing-cloud-page/) for some good info on creating a 'secure' cloud page. You can also likely build this externally as well utilizing the API if you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a dashboard, which requires someone actively visiting it to validate the number of inserted rows, I will recommend you to build an automation based approach.

You will need:

1. Automation to run hourly
2. Query activity selecting the rows inserted last hour (assuming a timestamp exists on your data)
3. Data extension to which the query activity will dump these X rows
4. Verification step, which will send an email to APIisStuck@example.com if above data extension holds 0 rows